# Printing Graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns in my Excel spreadsheet.  The first column is a date time column, the second column is a numerical value.

I want to print a chart so that on my X axis the date times are displayed (first column) and on the Y axis the numeric value is (the second column).

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[How to create a chart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/charts-i-how-to-create-a-chart-RZ001105505.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in tools in Excel to do this. Here's a link for an old version of Excel (you don't specify which one you are using): http://www.ncsu.edu/labwrite/res/gt/graphtut-home.html It will most likely work in a similar way in your version.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the best results doing this when I have formatted the date/time column in the form I want it to appear in the plot, prior to creating a scatter plot. ie. If I want Month/day/year Hour:min then I apply that format to the appropriate cells first. It's also possible to specify a custom format for the date/time. Excel 2010 seems to create the plots differently depending on the formatting.